# Not able to disable the element on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have html content which is kept in a common page. Hence i can only call the functions here. I cannot disable the button directly in html. I need to disable this in the js file. This is an angular page. Can anyone please help?

This is my code

HTML:

```
<button core-login-check item-click="button.click($event)" data-ng-if="button.type == 'button' && !button.skipSessionCheck" data-ng-disabled="!!button.disableOnInvalid && form.$invalid || button.disable && button.disable() || !!button.disableNotOnDirty && !form.$dirty" class="btn btn-info" data-i18n-content="button.label | call" data-ng-attr-qa-name="button-{{button.name}}" class="btn btn-info"></button>
```

JS:

```
formButtonSet.addButton('save', ['save', function(save) {
    return {
        type: 'button',
        click: save,
        label: {
            bundle: 'documents',
            key: 'modal/form/button/save'
        },
        disableOnInvalid: true
    };
}]);

var CreateDocumentFolderCtrl = function($scope, $modalInstance, customizationService,
        widgetsNotificationService, coreLoginService, documentService, parentDocFolderId) {

        var createDocumentFolderForm = {};

        createDocumentFolderForm.data = {
            parentDocFolderId: parentDocFolderId
        };

        createDocumentFolderForm.save = function() {
            documentService.doRestCall(documentService.createDocumentFolderReqInfo(createDocumentFolderForm.data)).then(
                coreLoginService.loginCheckLambda(function(result) {
                    if (result !== undefined) {
                        documentService.setOperationInfo('documentfolder-create', result);
                        widgetsNotificationService.addSuccessNotification('documents', 'notifications/folderCreated', {
                            documentFolder: result.title,
                            linkPath: 'documents/list/' + result.path
                        }, 0);
                    }
                    $modalInstance.close();
                }));
        };
```

Comment: @Cathy12341, where you added the function "doublesave()" ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to disable the button with `core-login-check` attribute?

Comment: yes. Please ignore the doublesave() function. I was just trying it myself. but failed.

Comment: it worked for me when i gave onclick="this.disabled=true" directly in the html. But i dont want to give like that

Comment: You can bind "ng-disabled" and set it to true in your JS.

Comment: no. it dint work for me